# Creating Swift framework that depends on another framework (objc)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform, frameworks

I'd like to create a dynamic framework in Swift. However, I'm building this framework on top of another dependency called `Parse`, which is Objective-C based. I've seen various tutorials on how to create a framework in Xcode but none has covered a framework with its own dependency.

I tried to create a framework project and then importing the dependency by import statement

```
import parse
```

Since `Parse` itself is a dependency in the main project, it should be available to my framework as well but unfortunately it throws an error.

> No such module 'Parse'

Then I thought to include the bridging header in my framework but then I came to know that bridging headers are not supported inside the framework.

So the question is: is it possible to create a Swift framework on top of Objc dependency in Xcode. And if so, how?

Edit:

I have gone through the suggested post but I am unable to build the project.

What I did now:
Included a `module.modulemap` file inside the `Parse` folder in framework:

```
module Parse {
  header "../../../Pods/Parse/Parse/Parse.h"
  export *
}
```

Result:

> 'Parse/ParseClientConfiguration.h' file not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Objective-c framework into Swift framework (Google Analytics + Cocoapod)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149371/import-objective-c-framework-into-swift-framework-google-analytics-cocoapod)

Comment: Did you try adding Parse as a dependency to your own framework?

Comment: No, it is not advised https://stackoverflow.com/a/32922605/3632958

Comment: Anyone meet the same problem can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529575/relative-path-for-headers-in-modulemap) out